# Why is this MySql query (on a partitioned table) always hitting the first partition?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I'm creating a table using partitioning as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `alert` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eventId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `occurred` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(occurred))
(PARTITION 28_06 VALUES LESS THAN (735413) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 29_06 VALUES LESS THAN (735414) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 30_06 VALUES LESS THAN (735415) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 01_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735416) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 02_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735417) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 03_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735418) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 04_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735419) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 05_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735420) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 06_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735421) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION 07_07 VALUES LESS THAN (735422) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Everything seems to be working correctly but when i perform the following query:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM alert WHERE occurred >= '2013-06-30' AND occurred <= '2013-07-01';
```

I get the following output:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | alert | 28_06,30_06,01_07 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Why does partition `28_06` appear in these results? When i am quite clearly selecting starting `2013-06-30`.

Any ideas?

---

Strangely, th following query seems to be fine:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM alert WHERE occurred >= '2013-07-02' AND occurred <= '2013-07-04';
```

output:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | alert | 02_07,03_07,04_07 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this a regression bug. I'm using version 5.6.11 on Mac OS X 10.8.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49754

A solution is to create a partition at the beginning that is never used. i.e.:

```
PARTITION unused VALUES LESS THAN (0)
```